# How do I see tags for all users on a model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using acts-as-taggable on. Two models: User and Posts.

```
Posts belongs_to :user
User has_many :posts
```

Posts acts-as-taggable.
Users acts-as-tagger

All of this is straightforward and is working. However, I have a use-case which may be outside of how this plugin works.

I want Posts to be able to be tagged by multiple users. When a tag is created on a post from a user, it does not show when you do the following:

```
p = Post.first
p.tag_list # this returns []
```

If you look at the SQL being generated it selects records where 'tagger_id' is NULL. The tagger_id is, of course, the user_id in this case and is very much not NULL.

If you back into it, however, you can get what you want.

```
p = Post.find(1) # get a post to work with
p.tags_from(p.user) # returns an array of the tags: ['cats','dogs','wildebeasts']
```

This works.

Now, the problem is I want another user to be able to come along and add a tag to the post. Maybe this user will think it is helpful. Let's just assume it makes sense to do so. Could be a moderator... whatever.

Given the above, how would I get a list of all the tags on a given post assuming that more than one user added tags?

Gratefully,

NJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about the plug-in you specified and I'm still learning Rails. But I don't think

```
p = Post.tag_list
```

would be what you want, anyways. You're asking for a taglist of the Post class rather than the taglist of a particular post. For example, if users have 'email' and 'name' columns, you also couldn't do:

```
u = User.names
u = User.emails
```

It doesn't really make sense. But you could do something like:

```
User.column_names
#=> ["id", "email", "hashed_password", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

Because that's a class method. Now, maybe tag_list is a class method, but it looks like it's used to find orphaned tags or something due to how it looks for null tag_givers.

But since I'm still new to Rails and I also don't know how your plugin works, here are some things you can try off the top of my head:

```
p = Post.find(1)
p.tag_list # p.column_name_of_the_column_that_holds_the_tags should work
# or, maybe pass in ALL users as an array
p.tags_from(User.all)
```

Lemme know what those do.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but some of this is peculiar to this plugin which is not terribly well documented and I'm not much one for digging into the source to figure things out. Not yet anyways. :)

Comment: I think I wrote too much. Did you try my suggestions in my last code block?

Comment: Don't worry about writing too much if you're on topic; sorry I didn't notice my duplicating your answer. Only thing I'd say is to edit and make the p an instance variable @p otherwise it wouldn't be available to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but:

```
p = Post.tag_list # this returns []

#should be 
#...
@post.find params[:id]
#...    
@post.tag_list
```

You're currently calling tag_list on the post class, rather than an instance of it.

Comment: You may be right. I will check this out later and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Try it out and let us know. Please accept Dobry Den's answer over mine if that is the problem.